# Jmeter - Bad request 400 received, although 200 is expected

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to understand why i have Bad request when i called my api, but works perfectly fine when using Postman/Supertest(JS).

MY request is as:
[image]

Headers as: 
[image]

Actual request as:
[image]

Actual response:
[image]

[image]

Although, the same request works perfectly fine using Postman.
[image]

[image]

-I tried Fiddler as well, request seems totally identical, but the response different.
[image]

-Using Jmeter v4, but the result is the same on 5.21

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending your request as body data with JMeter but in postman, you are sending it as form data. Check the postman headers accordingly.

[image]

In JMeter, for the form data, you have to check the `Use multipart/form-data` in your request sampler like this and add your parameters accordingly in the parameter tab instead of Body.

[image]